# Multi Touch Events in android

Tags: android, touch, multi-touch

Hi Here i want to solve the problem regarding multitouch in android. Is this possible to fire events of 2 buttons together if this is possible then how can i do this. please help regarding this. In my game application i want to do something after pressing two buttons together. How can i do this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is possible to aggregate two events to a single one oob. But it shouldn't be to hard to determine if two buttons were pressed simultaneously by using a [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) you bind to the parent element of the two buttons.

When an event is thrown and the onTouch() method is called. You got a bunch of arguments related to the event, like what kind of event it was (Action_Down, Action_Move, Action_Up etc.). You also get the information if the action was performed by the first oder by the second finger so this should give you the option to decide whether both buttons were touched.

[Here you can find a nice tutorial about multi touch support on Android](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2/1747).